# Sails Model.create

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm teaching myself Sails by following a book.

In the book the code should be:

```
Video.create(foundVideos).exec(function(err, videoRecordsCreated){
            if(err){
              console.log('err', err);

              return cb(err);
            }
            console.log('videoRecordsCreated', videoRecordsCreated);
          });
```

However after running `sails lift`
I am getting the following error:

> err { UsageError: Invalid new record. Details:   Got an array, but
>   expected new record to be provided as a dictionary (plain JavaScript
>   object).  Array usage is no longer supported as of Sails v1.0 /
>   Waterline 0.13.  Instead, please explicitly call `.createEach()`.
>
> ```
> at Object.success (/Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/Sails/brushfire/config/bootstrap.js:72:17)
> at afterwards (/Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/Sails/brushfire/node_modules/machinepack-youtube/node_modules/machine/lib/intercept-exit-callbacks.js:131:21)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/bliss/Documents/Coder/Sails/brushfire/node_modules/machinepack-youtube/node_modules/machine/lib/intercept-exit-callbacks.js:98:20)
> at ontimeout (timers.js:488:11)
> at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
> at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:283:5)   name: 'UsageError',   code: 'E_INVALID_NEW_RECORD',   details: 'Got an array, but expected
> ```
>
> new record to be provided as a dictionary (plain JavaScript object). 
>   Array usage is no longer supported as of Sails v1.0 / Waterline 0.13. 
>   Instead, please explicitly call `.createEach()`.' }

How to work around this problem?
It would seem like the code should work in a previous version of .create but now Array usage is no longer supported....

How to rewrite this code to work with the latest Sails version?

Comment: Can you please add the Model code and what you have in `foundVideos` ?

Comment: You just do what it says `Video.createEach` instead of `Video.create` . thats it. And to get the values you need to add `fetch()`.
So the full version `Video.createEach(foundVideos).fetch().exec..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *create* method of Waterline expects the parameter to be an object.

According to the error you are getting, it seems that the *foundVideos* is an array of objects. In that case, you need to use [createEach](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create-each) which expects array of objects. Like this:

```
  Video.createEach(foundVideos).fetch().exec(function(err, videoRecordsCreated){
    if(err){
      console.log('err', err);

      return cb(err);
    }
    console.log('videoRecordsCreated', videoRecordsCreated);
  }));
```

Comment: dont you need `.fetch()` ?

Comment: Yes you need a fetch after createEach if you need the created records otherwise it can be omitted. If that is omitted, your `videoRecordsCreated` will be undefined. Fetching involes extra query to the database. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: howcome .create does not need fetch but createEach needs fetch?  Also is the .exec a Javascript thing or is it only a Sails thing?

Comment: The `create` method indeed requires `fetch` method if you want the created document. You can see it [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create). The `exec` method is a chainable method provided by Waterline on every query. So, it is a Waterline/Sails native method.